# Modify jpeg metadata without resampling

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have seen several examples that call for using [SetPropertyItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem.aspx).  However, that causes the jpeg image to be resampled when the image is saved, thus losing image quality.

Is there a built-in way with .NET to modify the jpeg metadata (comments, author, subject, etc) without re-sampling the image?  I'd rather not have to parse the jpeg myself.